# Add odd numbers between a closed range to an array

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

I am doing code challenge where given two integers `l` and `r`, I have to print all the odd numbers between `i` and `r` (`i` and `r` inclusive). The function must return an array of integers denoting the odd numbers between `l` and `r`.

This is what I have so far

```
static int[] oddNumbers(int l, int r) {
    int[] theArray = new int[r];
    for (int i = l; i < theArray.length; i++) {
        if (i % 2 != 0) {
            for (int n = 0; n < theArray.length; n++) {
                theArray[n] = i;
            }
        }
    }
    return theArray;

}
```

So at the moment this code if you give it values 2 and 5 should return 3,5. However, this only returns 33333. What am I doing wrong? And how can I improve this code?

Comment: What is your reasoning for having that inner loop?

Comment: You only need one loop to solve this problem. Why create an array of R elements, when you can have at most ((R-L)+1)/2 elements.

Comment: Your problem is your inner loop, you're running through the entirety of the array and setting every value to whatever `i` is at the time.

Comment: Please clarify: Is the goal to have every odd number between `l` and `r` in the array or is the inner loop actually neccessary by the problem statement? I'm a bit confused why you would need two loops

Comment: the second inner loop is to loop through the array and add the odd number values to each index. Hench theArray[n] = i;

Comment: Separately: `int[] theArray = new int[r];` isn't going to give you the right length for the array. To figure out how to get the right length, consider how you can know how many odd numbers there are between `l` and `r` (inclusive).

Comment: @Dvorog could clarify ((R-L)+1)/2 please. The reason for me doing code challenges like this is to improve problem solving skills for problems like this.

Comment: Well lets say that L = 50 and R = 53.
In your code, you create an array of 53 elements, but you cannot have 53 elements because there are only 4 numbers in your interval (50,51,52,53).
So in this case ((R-L)+1)/2 will be 2 (and that is the number of odd numbers (51 and 53)).

Comment: @Dvorog great that makes a lot of sense now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would approach this by advancing the lower bound in the range to the next odd number, if not already odd, and then proceeding from there.

```
static int[] oddNumbers(int l, int r) {
    if (r <= l) return null;

    l = (l % 2) == 0 ? l + 1 : l;
    int size = ((r - l) / 2) + 1;

    int[] theArray = new int[size];

    for (int i=0; i < size; ++i) {
        theArray[i] = l + (i*2);
    }

    return theArray;
}
```

The real difficulty here is in formulating the logic to map a range of odd numbers onto a flat array.  Once we have done this, we can see that populating the array only requires a simple for loop.

Comment: is to correct for me assume that in the line l = (l % 2) == 0 ? l + 1 : l; you are checking if l is odd and if its not you are adding 1 to l in order to make it odd?

Comment: Yes, I make sure that the bottom of the range is always an odd number.  It is legitimate to assume that this can always be done since `r > l`.

Comment: could also clarify theArray[i] = l + (i*2); why are you using (i*2) to insert the value into the array?

Comment: Because we only want to insert odd numbers.

Answer (score 4):

We are in 2018 and do already have the amazing `Streams` since Java 8! With that you can solve such things in a single line! So it's worth it to take a look at it:

```
static int[] oddNumbers(int i, int j){
        return IntStream.rangeClosed(i, j).filter(num -> num % 2 == 1).toArray();
    }
```

(unless you really want to learn algorithms and not just solve the challenge!)

Answer (score 1):

I would delegate the work to a stream or list which can easily and dynamically manage the size of a selection.

Why should we bother about the size of a resulting array if we could make a simple transformation from an appropriate structure at the end?

```
static int[] oddNumbers(int l, int r) {
    return IntStream.iterate(l, i -> i <= r, i -> ++i)  
                    .filter(i -> i % 2 != 0)
                    .toArray();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution, the reason I didn't except it as the answer was because I am not that comfortable with Java 8 notations yet.

Comment: @user6248190, actually, `IntStream.iterate(seed, hasNext, next)` is from Java 9 ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
static int[] oddNumbers(int l, int r) {
    int[] theArray = new int[((r - l) / 2) + 1];
    for (int i = l % 2 == 0 ? l : l + 1, j = 0; i <= r; i += 2, j++)
        theArray[j] = i;


    return theArray;

}
```